Stochastic processes with variable dimensionalty
I am curious about stochastic processes where the dimensionality of the state space can grow over time which could have application to describe real world processes such evolution or technological progress. I imagine this has been done before but I don't know how to search for it.
To fix ideas the simplest way to represent it is with a stochastic vector whose coordinates are zero until a certain condition is met.
Conditions are represented by a a collection of regions of dimension $i$, $A_i \subset \mathbb{R}^i$.
Then the $i$-th element of the vector
$$
X_t = (X_{1t}, \dots, X_{it},\dots,X_{nt})
$$
follows a random walk $S_{it}$ as long as the process was within region $A_{i-1}$ in the previous time step
$$
X_{it} =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } X_{t-1} \in A_{i-1} \\
S_{it} &\text{ othw.}
\end{cases}.
$$
Then depending on what structure is imposed on the $A_i$ one can ask questions about the hitting times, explosion, stationary distributions etc.
The trivial example is the one in which the $S_{it}$ follow simple symmetric random walks forever once they cross a barrier given by $A_i$, i.e.,
$$
X_{it} =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } t < T_{A_{i-1}} \\
S_{it} &\text{ othw.}
\end{cases}
$$
where $T_{A_{i-1}} = \min_t \{t\in\mathbb{N}:S_{i-1,t} \in A_{i-1}\}$ is a hitting time.
